# Webpage flickers in localhost, but not when it is webhosted

Tags: jquery, html, css

[flicker on localhost. short clip](http://screenr.com/h7E8) . White flash observed when the page refreshes.

While it is hosted, [website link](http://geezus1.atwebpages.com) , it doesn't flicker at all.

This is really weird.

Comment: Why the downvote ? More information required ?

Comment: In the movie, the page refresh?

Comment: Yes. the short clip is showing the page refreshing twice.

Comment: It's not a flicker, its the white background behind the png. It appears as a flickr on localhost because the background loads almost instantly. On the webserver it takes a good  few seconds to load in so you don't see it as a flicker.

Comment: Oh, you are referring to the default white background before the wooden background ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not up to you to determine how a browser chooses to render a page.  Browsers will pick which order to draw things in.  Sure, you can influence it in a lot of best-practice ways, but I would suggest that trying to optimize your site for loading your **huge** (2MB PNG!) background image prior to rendering isn't the way to go.

In short, this loading order is normal and there is nothing that you should do about it.

Comment: +1 Good point.  @TheKraven: Might I suggest using the Save for Web and Devices option in Photoshop?  It can decrease your file size by a lot.

Comment: @cereallarceny, It was pretty easy to spot.  Even on my 30mbit cable connection, it took 9 seconds to download.  :-D

Comment: Gotta love it.  Shame on you for not being "progressive" and demanding your own personal fiber-optic line.  ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, I got to do something with the 2MB png..

Comment: @TheKraven, Use JPEG (suitable for this type of image), and set the quality level around 60%.  It will still be huge, but not so bad.  Then, set a background color (for when the background isn't there) to something similar to the general color the image.

Comment: Will do, trying it out soon :)